# Loading Images in Listview WPF like Windows 7

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, listviewitem

Currently I am showing many images (image thumbnails) in listview. For sake of memory management I have use virtualization in Listview and it does its job.

Now what I want is to show a default icon instead on original images thumb and then loading original thumb a bit later. have a look at below snap [image]

Can any one suggest how can I achieve this ?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753174.aspx). You basically provide two properties, one with your actual loading of the thumbnail, and one with a preloaded default icon. The one with the full thumbnail is going to be `IsAsync="True"` and while that runs in the background, the other non async binding will just grab the icon to display in the meantime.

Comment: I'm sorry, is that a question? What kind of performance issues are you having? Make sure you set the IsAsync flag on the binding, with the actual bitmap loading. Try to minimize context switches or property change raises to the ui thread, also if you are loading the image by yourself, remember to freeze it so it can be passed cross thread boundaries. Otherwise: No idea, check your output; debug; profile.

Comment: Is there any way like Default Image get loaded by default and then control go to fetch actual image after UI is loaded. Currently It tries get actual image first then sleeps

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but Priority binding is exactly for that. It will call each binding eventually, but in a fixed order from first to last. So your first bindings must be IsAsync=True otherwise there is no point in doing that. The last property, which should be the fastest, has IsAsynch=False and just returns an preloaded placeholder image, of course no actual loading must happen in this bound getter. If you still have issues you might have to update your question and show some code whats going wrong.